# How can I get arbitrary command line arguments past yarn and webpack-dev-server?

Tags: electron, webpack-dev-server, yarnpkg

I'm building an Electron-based command line tool. Users will invoke it from the command line, and then it'll open a normal Electron window (which is why I'm bothering with Electron & webpack, instead of using something simpler like `nexe`), influenced by what they entered via CLI. I'm using webpack-dev-server v2.4.5 to develop the Electron UI.

I have an npm script, `dev`, that invokes webpack-dev-server with all the necessary build options. Unfortunately, when I add my own arguments at the  command prompt, something is consuming them and they don't make it to my electron application.

My npm script:

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --config=./webpack.dev.config.js $*",
```

The `$*` is a trick I found that appears to expand as additional arguments.

I want to pass these args to my node script: `--live --speed fast`. So, I run `yarn dev somefile.ext -- --live --speed fast`, and then I see:

```
yarn run v1.3.2
warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
$ webpack-dev-server --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --config=./webpack.dev.config.js $* somefile.ext --live --speed fast

...<webpack-dev-server> CLI usage info

Unknown argument: live
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

(Yes, the `$*` appears as-is in the command, which seems odd. But it also brings in those extra args, so that's good.) It seems clear that `yarn` passed the extra arguments on to `webpack-dev-server`, which then attempted to consume them and failed.

If I omit the `--`, I get the same output, but without the yarn warning about it being unnecessary.

If I run bypass the npm script entirely, I get similar results:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --config=./webpack.dev.config.js -- somefile.ext --live --speed fast
```

Produces:

```
ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js --live --speed fast
```

In this case, it appears `webpack-dev-server` faithfully passed the extra args onto `dev-server`, which then choked on them.

Is it possible to get these extra options past webpack-dev-server? Am I going to have to hack this 12 levels down, through all of webpack's guts?

All the help I can find online is about people trying to wire up their dev vs. prod flag, and so all the advice is about using env vars instead (e.g. `ENV=dev webpack ...`). That seems inappropriate here, because the CLI options I want to pass and develop against will be provided explicitly by end-users.

Any advice is appreciated.